# Setting different content based on property value

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am kind of lost what strategy to take. I need to do the following:

I have a toggle button as a base class. This button has all the properties as normal button, plus IsChecked, which tells us whether button is toggled or not.

I want to create a style (or a template) for ToggleButton. Basically it must inherit original style from ToggleButton, and add this:

IsChecked=True: Set ToolTip to "Collapse" and show this content (minus sign)

```
<Path Margin="2" Stroke="ForeGround property on control" Data="M0,5 H10" StrokeThickness="3" />
```

IsChecked=False, Set ToolTip tp "Expand" and show this content (plus sign)

```
<Path Margin="2" Stroke="ForeGround property on control" Data="M0,5 H10 M5,0 V10" StrokeThickness="3" />
```

I tried several approaches and always came up with some exception that I could not resolve.

Another approach can be to have one content only (plus sign), but divided to two lines:

```
<Grid>
    <Path Margin="2" Stroke="ForeGround property on control" Data="M0,5 H10" StrokeThickness="3" />
    <Path x:Name="verticalLine" Margin="2" Stroke="ForeGround property on control" Data="M5,0 V10" StrokeThickness="3" />
</Grid>
```

And them hange visibility of verticalLine based on expanded / collapsed state.

I made some progress:

```
<Style x:Key="myToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid>
                <Path Margin="2" Stroke="Black" Data="M0,5 H10" StrokeThickness="3" />
                <Path x:Name="verticalLine" Margin="2" Stroke="Black" Data="M5,0 V10"  StrokeThickness="3" />
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="verticalLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="verticalLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The only thing that I cannot do now is set Stroke to Foreground color of ToggleButton. I have tried all I rememberd, from TemplatedParent to AncestorType, and no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the final solution:

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Path Margin="4" Data="M0,5 H10" Stretch="UniformToFill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}" StrokeThickness="3" />
                    <Path x:Name="verticalLine" Margin="4" Data="M5,0 V10" Stretch="UniformToFill" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Control.Foreground}" StrokeThickness="3" />
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="verticalLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="verticalLine" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `Path.Data` according to the `ToggleButtons IsChecked`property:

```
                  <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter Property="Content">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Path Margin="2" Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" StrokeThickness="3">
                                        <Path.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="Path">
                                                <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,5 H10 M5,0 V10 "/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,5 H10"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Path.Style>
                                    </Path>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Expanded"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
```

Comment: Hi Miklos, I cannot set the Content into the style, I need to have this style as resource, available to many instances of control.